# How to change console output in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

How can I change the output format in Pycharm to make it similar to the one that R-Studio has - line of code - corresponding output
line of code - corresponding output
line of code - corresponding output
etc..
[image]
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi read his question again.  He's not asking about the code in the image, he's asking about how to get the console to look a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your pycharm output doesn't look the same is because it's only executing the code and then exiting the interpreter.  Whereas it would appear that R-Studio is executing code in terminal mode; which keeps the interpreter running allowing you to execute code on the fly.

Pycharm CAN be run in a similar fashion but it's likely not exactly what you're looking for.

If you put a breakpoint in your code and execute your script in debug it will pause at your breakpoint and then allow you to execute code on the fly in the console.